# Which power series in $K_0(\textrm{Var}_\mathbb C)[[t]]$ are exponents?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R=K_0(\textrm{Var}_\mathbb C)$ denote the Grothendieck ring of complex quasi-projective varieties. It is known that, for every smooth quasi-projective variety $X$ of dimension $d$, in the ring $R[[t]]$ one has the equality of power series
$$
1+\sum_{n\geq 1}[\textrm{Hilb}^n(X)]t^n=\Bigl(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}[\textrm{Hilb}^n(\mathbb C^d;0)]t^n \Bigr)^{[X]}.
$$ 
Here $\textrm{Hilb}^n(\mathbb C^d;0)$ is the punctual Hilbert scheme of $\mathbb C^d$ (its points are length $n$ subschemes of $\mathbb C^d$, concentrated at the origin).

I know a proof of this result, using general properties of the power structure on $R[[t]]$.
But I do not know what the "story" is behind this remarkable equality. I was told such an equality was *conjectured* some time before its proof. So I am asking two questions (the first one is just a curiosity):

1. What led to conjecture such an equality?
2. Is there a characterization of those power series $A(t)=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}[A_n]t^n\in R[[t]]$ which can be written as exponents (with respect to the usual power structure on $R$)?

**Added**. To give a power structure on a ring $R$ means, intuitively, to say what it means for a power series to be "raised" to an element of $R$: more specifically, one wants to define a map
$$(1+tR[[t]])\times R\to 1+tR[[t]],\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}a_nt^n,m)\mapsto (1+\sum_{n\geq 1}a_nt^n)^m,$$ so that the usual properties of the exponential should hold. (Reference: Gusein-Zade, Luengo, Melle-Hern$\acute{\textrm{a}}$ndez have a series of papers on this). For instance, on $R=\mathbb Z$, the exponential is a power structure. Amazingly, to give a power structure it is enough to specify the power series
$(1-t)^{-[X]}$, and in the case of $R=K_0(\textrm{Var}_\mathbb C)$ we set the latter equal to the Kapranov zeta function of $X$, namely
$$\zeta_{[X]}(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0}[\textrm{Sym}^n(X)]t^n.$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably the two instances of $\mathbb{C}^d$ are supposed to be $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Comment: Thanks! fixed. (that was the example I had in mind while writing...)

Comment: It seems cleaner to declare that $\text{Hilb}^0$ is a point than to separate out the summation like that. Anyway, maybe this is too naive a comment, but one expects the LHS to behave something like $\sum {X \choose n} t^n$, and this is of course $(1 + t)^X$ by the binomial theorem. But I guess there is richer infinitesimal structure in the Hilbert scheme than just collections of $n$ disjoint points in $X$ and that richer structure is responsible for the extra stuff that appears on the RHS.

Comment: What does $[X]^{[Y]}$ mean in general? Or, in what generality should it be defined?

Comment: @AllenKnutson: I added something. The authors I quote explain this very well, e.g. in http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605467.pdf.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: There is no such beast. It is radically different to define $f(T)^{[Y]}$, where $f(0)=1$, thank do define $[X]^{[Y]}$.